# Apple `ld` and `-ObjC` Switch?

Tags: objective-c, linker

What does this mean (from Apple's `ld` man page):

```
 -ObjC       Loads all members of static archive libraries that implement
             an Objective-C class or category.
```

I don't think I have ever seen the description, and I don't know what it means to 'load' archive members at the link stage. It is listed under "Options that control libraries."

Apple requires static linking for iDevices, but `-Bstatic` appears to be missing. Is Apple using `-ObjC` to force static linking?

Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good description regarding how Static Libraries and Objective C work:
http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2006/03/13/static_objc_lib/

Typically if you're using static libraries, you need to let the linker know that it contains Objective-C code. This is so it's able to correctly hook up ObjC symbols and references, as they vary from traditional C and C++ (Objective C is very dynamic in comparison).